# How to set path pygobject Macos catalina installing PyGTK

Tags: macos, pygtk, pygobject

I have installed through brew pygobject3 and it is
/usr/local/Cellar/pygobject3/3.36.1
I have tried to export to the right path but while trying to install PyGTK I am still getting:

configure: error: Package requirements (pygobject-2.0 >= 2.21.3) were not met:

No package 'pygobject-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PYGOBJECT_CFLAGS
and PYGOBJECT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have PyGObject fully installed:

```
$ brew install python3 gobject-introspection gtk+3 adwaita-icon-theme
```

If you are still getting errors, I have seen issues with the homebrew version of libffi available, which isn't linked automatically:

```
$ libffi_path="$(brew ls libffi | grep pkgconfig | xargs dirname)"
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${libffi_path}:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:-}"
```